# Python ciscotelnet

Tags: python, telnet, cisco

I just installed "ciscotelnet.py" from https://github.com/sergeyzelyukin/cisco-telnet

When I try run:

```
import ciscotelnet
with ciscotelnet.CiscoTelnet("10.3.99.34", verbose = False) as cisco:
  if cisco.login(final_mode=CiscoTelnet.MODE_ENABLE, user="admin", user_pass="x", enable_pass="x"):
    cisco.cmd("sh interface status")
```

Then I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\cisco.py", line 4, in <module>
    if cisco.login(final_mode=CiscoTelnet.MODE_ENABLE, user="admin", user_pass="atmadmin", enable_pass="cisco"):
NameError: name 'CiscoTelnet' is not defined
```

What I do wrong? I'm newbie in Python.

Answer (score 0):

replace the first import with:

```
from ciscotelnet import CiscoTelnet
```

so you can use CiscoTelnet always instead of ciscotelnet.CiscoTelnet. This means that you should replace

```
with ciscotelnet.CiscoTelnet....
```

for

```
with CiscoTelnet(
```

Comment: Thank you,  now I have error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\cisco.py", line 6, in <module>
    if cisco.login(final_mode=CiscoTelnet.MODE_ENABLE, user="admin", user_pass="x", enable_pass="x"):
AttributeError: type object 'CiscoTelnet' has no attribute 'MODE_ENABLE'"  I opened ciscotelnet.py file and I see this mode!

Comment: seems that the doc's code you are following is not  correct.